# Is there a way to grab both keyframes and markers in blender?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have lots of camera animation binded to markers to switch between the cameras.
I can grab and scale keyframes, and the same goes for markers, but I cannot grab them together. Every time I need to move keyframes and markers I have to do it separately and this is annoying.
Is there a way to move them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dopesheet's View / Sync markers.

[image]

Comment: Lol. It';s a necropost, brought by the bots to be active. The Skynet will definitely kill us all one day. :-/

Comment: This option has moved.  I'm using v3.4.1 and it's now in Dope Sheet > Marker > Sync Markers

Answer (score 1):

Scale? After selecting the keyframes (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, in case thats the problem you are getting) click <kbd>G</kbd> and then you can move the keyframes either by using a mouse, or entering the number on your numpad.

Comment: It seems that moving markers this way works, but scaling does not.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't.